# Connect 30 different clients GA4 and UA to Make / HTTP

Tags: http, google-analytics, oauth, make.com, integromat-apps

What is the easiset way from the clients perspective to authorise me to connect to their GA4 & UA properties? I have to connect more than 30 to Make (formerly Integromat). I can use a HTTP calls

Client can not add my external email address on their google instance to give me access. I need alternative & very user friendly options please

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to use Oauth2 request authorization of the client to access their data.

You can store the refresh token in your database asdocated with the user.  Then your code will be able to request a new access token when ever you need

Comment: My connections used to work, now I keep getting this error, any thoughts please:
Code 401: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See Integrating Google Sign-In into your web app  |  Authentication  |  Google Developers.

Comment: invalid authentication credential can be a number of things.  But it sounds like your access token isnt valid.   Edit your question and include your code.